# Bash script to apply operation to each file found by find

Tags: bash

I'm trying to execute an operation to each file found by find - with a specific file extension (wma). For example, in python, I would simply write the following script:

```
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if file.endswith('wma'):
        name = file[:-4]
        command = "ffmpeg -i '{0}.wma' '{0}.mp3'".format(name)
        os.system(command)
```

I know I need to execute something similar to

```
find -type f -name "*.wma" \
    exec ffmpeg -i {}.wma {}.mp3;
```

But obviously this isn't working or else I wouldn't be asking this question =]

Comment: use this : `-exec ffmpeg -i {} {}.mp3 \;`

Comment: I tried adding the hyphen to exec (using my original proposed bash script) and I got the error "find: illegal option -- t".

Comment: Did you notice the escaped semi-colon at the end of the first comment? `\;` to signify the end of `-exec` and not part of it? The complete find would be `find /path/to/dir -type f -exec ffmpeg -i {}.wma {}.mp3 \;` **(space left for emphasis)**

Comment: At first I didn't, but then I noticed it, tried it, and it still didn't work. I figured out that the "-- t" complaint was because I didn't specify find to search through the current directory, but even "find "." -type f -name "*.wma" \ -exec ffmpeg -i {} {}.mp3 \;" raised an error. "-exec: unknown primary or operator"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time it's better to use `read` when parsing input than doing **word splitting** with `for` and depending on `IFS` as there's risk with unexpected pathname expansion.

```
while IFS= read -u 4 -r LINE; do
    ffmpeg -i "$LINE" "${LINE%.*}.mp3"
done 4< <(exec find -type f -name '*.wma')
```

Or use `readarray` (Bash 4.0+)

```
readarray -t FILES < <(exec find -type f -name '*.wma')

for FILE in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    ffmpeg -i "$FILE" "${FILE%.*}.mp3"
done
```

Comment: Unlike @Liviu Chircu's solution, the first script actually escaped the file names with spaces. However, it only executed the command on the first file in the list. I'm not sure why - it could be because of the command being executed? However, the second script did not run for me.

Comment: @hlin117 You can add `echo`'s before and after the `ffmpeg` command to see if the script is continuing or not. The second script would require Bash 4.0 or newer. You can see your bash's version with `bash --version`. Also make sure you run your scripts with bash and not just sh i.e. `bash script.sh`

Comment: @hlin117 I now see the probably cause. `ffmpeg` might actually be eating up the input. So using another file descriptor for would solve it. I made an update on the first script.

Comment: As another note: `ffmpeg` would ask for verification if it wants to overwrite a file. You can add `-y` option to make it overwrite files without asking.

Comment: Cool! The first script worked beautifully. Thank you. (The comment about the -y option for ffmpeg is good too. I didn't know about it.)

Comment: What about filenames with newlines?

Comment: It's rare however that's still applicable with `-d $'\0'` and `-print0`. `-d ''` is probably synonymous but I would have to check that again.

Answer (score 2):

Sticking to the basics always gets the job done (does not handle spaces in filenames):

```
for f in $(find "." -type f -name "*.wma"); do ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f//wma/mp3}"; done
```

Starting from [konsolebox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445221/konsolebox)'s suggestions below, I've come up with this complete version:

```
find "." -type f -name "*.wma" | while read -d $'\n' f; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f//wma/mp3}"; done
```

Comment: I executed: the command above, and I received the error: "find: illegal option -- t". Does this command run for you?

Comment: I executed the modified script, and it ran. Unfortunately, some of my files have spaces in them, so it didn't work. Can you modify the script so it takes in files that have spaces?

Comment: Try enclosing $f in double quotes

Comment: "for f in $(find "." -type f -name "*.wma"); do ffmpeg -i "$f" ${f//wma//mp3}; done" and "for f in $(find "." -type f -name "*.wma"); do ffmpeg -i $f ${f//wma//mp3}; done" seem to do the same exact thing. Both commands are trying to apply "ffmpeg -i ..." to each space-separated word in the filenames. For example, if you have the name "hello world.wma", it'll try to apply the command to "hello" and "world.wma".